# How should I go about creating the same hash ID for the same data which is in random order in Python?

Tags: python, hash

I am reading in files through Python and have the problem of creating an identifier for the last 500 bytes or so in the file.  I would like the identifier to be the same for any file that shares the same exact bytes in that chunk, however the actual bytes can be in any order.  If a byte is missing or added I would like the identifier to be different.  I am looking for any design or implementation advice people may have as speed is important.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hashing isn't exactly my area of expertise but what comes to mind is sorting the bytes based on their numerical values and then hashing that.

Comment: I'm not expert either but maybe try make a collections.Counter object perhaps. OF course if one byte is missing but that same byte was also added then you will get the same hash.

Comment: Sorting the bytes is an efficient and simple way. Sort the bytes, compute MD5/CRC-32/Adler-32/whatever, done.

Answer (score 4):

Implementing @NRaf's idea:

```
import hashlib

def lasthash(data):
    m = hashlib.md5("".join(sorted(data)))
    return m.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 4):

> the problem of creating an identifier for the last 500 bytes or so in the file.
>   I would like the identifier to be the same for any file that shares the same 
>   exact bytes in that chunk, however the actual bytes can be in any order. 
>   If a byte is missing or added I would like the identifier to be different.

If the multiplicity is important (meaning that it matters whether how many times a certain byte occurs), use *[collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#module-collections)* and then run a *[frozenset](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)* hash on its *items()*:

```
>>> hash(frozenset(Counter(f.read()[-500:]).items()))
133156838395276
```

If the multiplicity isn't important, then you can use a *frozenset* hash directly:

```
>>> hash(frozenset(f.read()[-500:]))
814428559884891156
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a histogram of the data, that is, count the number of each of the 256 possible bytes.

This will be much faster than sort and hash approach.

```
count = [0]*256
for byte in data:
    count[byte] += 1
```